# How to put meta tags for each news post PHP (no wordpress)

Tags: php, function, tags, meta, head

Hello i don't look for wordpress plugin or something. This is my php page.

```
<html>
<head>
blablablalba
<?php to_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
bla bla bla
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
    $select=mysqli_query($con,"select....");
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
         echo "bla bla bla";
         to_head("<title>asd</title><meta itemprop="name" content="Najnovije informacije iz sveta hostinga">...");
    } 
}
?>
bla bla bla
</body>
</html>
```

I need to set for each news post diffrent meta tags and put in head.. How can i do that?

Comment: write your sql statements in the head... you can't jump like in your code.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7 somehow thay do that in php..

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill variables, then echo variables to html...par example

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
$head = "bla bla";
$body = "bla bla";
    $select=mysqli_query($con,"select....");
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
         $body .= "bla bla bla";
         $head .= "<title>asd</title><meta itemprop="name" content="Najnovije informacije iz sveta hostinga">...";
    } 
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<?= $head ?>
</head>
<body>
<?= $body ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have header.php and news.php in news.php i include header.php and in news.php i need to set for posts diffrent variable, so mysqli_query before <head> don't work for me

Comment: @user1721620 As far as I know, there is no way in php to change tags earlier in the document.

Comment: yes, there is in cms php-fusion with function with add_to_head(); but i don't know and i can't find how works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("header.php");
//some mysqli_query with $seo='tags...';
//this is body of document
//footer of document footer.php start
?></body>
</html>
<?php
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$buffer=str_replace("#</head>#",$seo."</head>",$buffer);
echo $buffer;
//end of footer.php
?>
```

this is what i looking for so in php to set your meta tag from query to head
offcourse this can expend but idea is this. tnx evryone for reply and comment..